# Cassandra 4.1.x Upgrade: Need Clarification on SSTable Upgrade Necessity

Tags: cassandra

We are planning to upgrade our Cassandra cluster from version 3.11.12 to 4.1.x. I have read that Cassandra version 4.1.x maintains backward compatibility with version 3.11.x, indicating that there might be no need to upgrade SSTables. However, I couldn't find definitive documentation confirming whether an SSTable upgrade is required or not.

Before proceeding, I wanted to seek clarification on whether an SSTable upgrade is necessary for the transition from Cassandra 3.11.12 to 4.1.x. If anyone has insights or if there are specific steps related to SSTables that we should follow during the upgrade, kindly provide guidance or direct me to relevant resources.

Also please share how to check the current sstable version as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is always recommended to perform sstableupgrade while you're at your current C* version, just to make sure there are no surprises. If the SSTables are already on the right version, it will be a quick no-op and you can proceed to move on with your [other upgrade procedures](https://docs.datastax.com/en/luna-cassandra/docs/guides/upgrade/overview.html).

There are places to find the SSTable version.

- You could list the data files within your *data_directory* to find (or)
- See [this table](https://docs.datastax.com/en/home/docs/compatibility.html#VcompatNote) on some official documentation (or)
- Do a code dive to find the [Format `big`](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.12/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/format/big/BigFormat.java#L113) and Version (`me`) info directly from the C* codebase repository.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in order to finish the upgrade process, we should do a sstable upgrade. Even though Cassandra offers backward compatibility, it is still necessary to maintain the sstable file format in accordance with version recommendations.

Steps to keep in mind when carrying out a sstable update.

1. After the binary upgrade, it's not required to execute right away. Once the binary upgrade has finished for every node across all DCs (if the cluster is multi-DC), we may proceed with the sstable upgrade.
2. sstable upgrades should be carried out node by node throughout clusters. Cluster performance may be impacted by parallel operations since they demand additional disk I/O.

It is possible the data files that are kept on disk serve as the basis for the SSTable version. The /data directory contains the files that you can access.

3.x version data files in the md*.db format.
4.x version data files in the nb*.db format